# how to extract the apk of my app in delphi 10.3?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to extract the APK of my application when it is installed, I know there is an application called APK EXTRACTOR which performs this task, but in my case I want to extract the apk myself from delphi code.

So far I have only been able to find the APKs of pre-installed applications on the phone in the path "/system/app" and "system/priv-app" but internally I cannot find the apk of my app.
[image: Inside each folder is its apk]
[image: Inside each folder is its apk]

Comment: The screenshot is unnecessarily large - can you please reduce it down to 25%? Sure this Q only needs the Delphi tag? Users might lurk on tags only and would then miss your Q....

Comment: Commonly it would be `/​data/​app/`​

Answer (score 0):

I recall a long time ago a file manager did a backup
of all the applications.
It puts all the APKs in a directory on the phone
It was on the GOOGLE market.
It might help to find out how he does it.